# PHP Javascript - Array multidimensional error

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

In practice, I create an array in PHP that then I pass to a JavaScript function.

So far so good. The array that the functions recieves is the following:

```
[[{"firstname": "Micheal", "lastname": "Brown"}], [{"car": "Ford", "model": "Fiesta"}]]
```

My problem is to get all the first array, that is this: `{"firstname": "Micheal", "lastname": "Brown"}`

and also the second array this: `{"car": "Ford", "model": "Fiesta"}`

I tried with `alert (array [0])` but it only shows me this `[`

How can I do this?

I'll explain:

this is my php file:

```
class UserClasses
{
     public $firstname;
     public $lastname;
}

class CarClasses
{
     public $car;
     public $model;
}

if(isset($_POST['name'])){
     populate($_POST['name']);
}

function populate(){
//I abbreviated the function for simplicity

   $arrayUser = array();
   $arrayCar = array();

   $user = new UserClasses();
   $user->firstname = "Micheal";
   $user->lastname = "Brown";
   array_push($arrayUser, $user);

   $car = new CarClasses();
   $car->car = "Ford";
   $car->model = "Fiesta";
   array_push($arrayCar, $car);
   $arrayFinal = array($arrayUser, $arrayCar);

   print json_encode($arrayFinal);
}
```

and this is the function in javascript:

```
//Ajax for calling php function
$.post('Classes.php', { name: name }, function(data){
    var array = JSON.parse(data);
    var arrayT = array[0];
    alert(arrayT);
});
```

Comment: You should learn the difference between JSON and an actual array.

Comment: Add your JavaScript function to the question please. Your problem is, that your JSON is interpreted as a string in JavaScript, instead of an array of objects. To help you solve the problem we need a glimpse at your JS code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what is happening with your code: you're accessing the first element of a JSON string, so my guess is you will get its first character: `[`.

You need to convert your string into an actual array before accessing it!

Use [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

> The JSON.parse() method parses a JSON string, constructing the JavaScript value or object described by the string.
>
> - [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)

For example you can do:

```js
const json = '[[{"firstname": "Micheal", "lastname": "Brown"}], [{"car": "Ford", "model": "Fiesta"}]]'

// that's what you have
console.log(json[0])

// that's what you want
array = JSON.parse(json)
console.log(array[0])
```

Comment: *you're accessing the first element of a JSON object* -> You're accessing the first element of a JSON **string** thus returning the first character.

Comment: I tried but give me this now:
[object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object]
, I modified the post by adding my code

Comment: Of course, you're are using `alert`, it will never show you the actual object, just `[object Object]`. Always use `console.log` to debug your code!!!

Comment: Great Stefano, Don't forget to upvote / accept answer(s) you felt helped solve you problem for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you are using `json_encode` to pass PHP array to JS, it encodes it to a [JSON](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp) string. You have to parse it using `JSON.parse()` and only then the json string is transformed to regular array which you can use.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse data and use it:

```
    var arr = '<?php echo '[[{"firstname": "Micheal", "lastname": "Brown"}], [{"car": "Ford", "model": "Fiesta"}]]'; ?>';
    var parsedarr =  JSON.parse(arr);

    for(var i=0;i<parsedarr.length;i++){
        console.log(parsedarr[i][0]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with **3** different *Data Types*:

- a **PHP** Multidimensional Array
- a **JSON** String
- a **Javascript** Object

Each needs to be converted into the next.

- A **PHP Array** is converted into a **JSON String**, via `json_encode()` (in **PHP**)
- A **JSON String** is converted into a **Javascript Object**, via `JSON.parse()` (in **Javascript**)

Now you have a Javascript `Object` which you can interrogate and manipulate using Javascript.

---

**PHP Multidimensional Array:**

```
$My_PHP_Array = array(

    array(

        'firstname' => 'Michael'
        'lastname' => 'Brown'
    ),

    array(

        'car' => 'Ford'
        'model' => 'Fiesta'
    )
);
```

**Convert PHP Multidimensional Array to JSON String:**

```
json_encode($My_PHP_Array);
```

**JSON String:**

```
'{
    [
        [{
            "firstname": "Micheal",
            "lastname": "Brown"
        }],

        [{
            "car": "Ford",
            "model": "Fiesta"
        }]
    ]
}'
```

**Convert JSON String to Javascript Object:**

```
var myJavascriptObject = JSON.parse(myJSONString);
```

**Javascript Object:**

```
myJavascriptObject = {
    [
        [{
            "firstname": "Micheal",
            "lastname": "Brown"
        }],

        [{
            "car": "Ford",
            "model": "Fiesta"
        }]
    ]
};
```